# How to split csv file based on column value in cloud dataflow python sdk

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to read csv file from GCS using the ReadFromText and like to split into multiple file based on column values.

```
See sample data below 
Col1    Col2    Col3
Value1  data    date
value2  data    date_1
Value3  data    date_2
Value4  data    date_3
Value5  data    date
```

I want to create the folder namely date,date_1..3 and file name prefix with date corresponding data should be load to the file .

Answer (score 0):

Process each element to generate a KV, where the Key becomes the metadata about the location you would like the Value to land.  Then look at using [dynamic destinations](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#writeDynamic--) to write out the files.

An example of using the Key with FileIO is [in this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887072/is-there-a-way-to-write-one-file-for-each-record-with-apache-beam-fileio).

Comment: I would like to solve this in python SDK. Please let me know if anything we can do in python.

Comment: You can use take a look at this example - https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/multiple_output_pardo.py